# HSQLDB + insert data + error statement

Tags: java, swing, hsqldb

I have an error message that I can not solve. I want to log the data from a JFrame (textefield) in a table

I use Eclipse + HSQLDB. I get my data from textefield in a JFrame. I give my récupre correctly but I get an error statement Does not generate a result set.

My table: Sales (ID is auto-increment integer, string quantity, total string)

```
package Fabriques;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import Donnees.MyException;
import Donnees.Ventes;

public class FabVentes {

    private static FabVentes fabVen;
    private FabVentes(){}


    public static FabVentes getInstance(){
        if(FabVentes.fabVen==null) FabVentes.fabVen=new FabVentes();
        return FabVentes.fabVen;
    }

    /*requetes select*/
    private String insertVentes = "insert into ventes values (?,?,?)";

    private PreparedStatement prepinsertVentes;

    public void demarrerConnexion(Connection connexionEnCours) throws SQLException {
        this.prepinsertVentes=connexionEnCours.prepareStatement(this.insertVentes);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource") 
    public Ventes ajouter(Integer ID,final String Quantite,final String Total) throws SQLException{
        this.prepinsertVentes.setString(1,null);
        this.prepinsertVentes.setString(2,Quantite);
        System.out.println(Quantite); //-> I Get my string
        this.prepinsertVentes.setString(3,Total);
        System.out.println(Total); //-> I Get my string
        ResultSet resultat=this.prepinsertVentes.executeQuery();

        Ventes v=null;
        while(resultat.next())
            v=new Ventes(null,resultat.getString(2),resultat.getString(3));
        return v;
    }
}
```

The error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: statement does not generate a result set
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.checkStatementType(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at Fabriques.FabVentes.ajouter(FabVentes.java:38)
    at Metier.Metier.ajouter(Metier.java:12)
    at IHM.JPanelVentes$1.mouseClicked(Fenetre.java:262)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: statement does not generate a result set
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 38 more
```

Thanks for your help,

Laure

Answer (score 4):

The `executeQuery` method is for executing select statements, which is why it returns a `ResultSet`.  Your insert query doesn't product a `ResultSet`.

Instead, you should call [the `executeUpdate` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate--).

> Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

It returns the count of rows affected.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are trying to get result for an insert statement? You should try using:

```
int rowsModified = this.prepinsertVentes.executeUpdate();
```